# IS storing data without user signing in on flutter app possible?

Tags: ios, flutter

I'm making a card game for apple appstore that consists of 5 decks, 2 of them being free to play and 3 of them needed payment to be unlocked. I am not currently planning to do a login for my app. Would there be any way for me to track whether or not the user has paid and unlocked a particular deck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect if user bought something and you need to do it in different devices and even in the same device if user uninstall / install again, you'll need to implement a sign up strategy.

If you don't care about cross device, cross installations.. then you could generate an installation id that you're sure to be unique and send it to the server the first time the app is opened and use that to identify activity on that device/installation in the future.

You could use a uuid or any other identifier that you know that won't be used by anyone else.

So the flow would be:

- App opened for first time
- Generate installation id
- Store it locally
- Send installation id to server
- Send it in the future to identify current installation